# XQuery: "toString method" including the elements

Tags: xquery

The following xQuery produces the following result:

```
for $i in db:open('foo')/bar
return $i/geo
```

Result:

```
<geo type="null"/>
<geo type="null"/>
<geo type="object">
   <type>Point</type>
   <coordinates type="array">
      <value type="number">41.00502344</value>
      <value type="number">29.05639393</value>
   </coordinates>
</geo>
```

I would like to make the result as string and attach some information, e.g.

```
for $i in db:open('foo')/bar
return concat("some text ", $i/geo)
```

The  "problem" is, that the concat method as well as some other "toString" methods remove the the tags, the result looks like this:

```
some text  some text  some text Point41.0050234429.05639393
```

I would like to have a result which looks like this:

```
some text <geo type="null"/>  some text <geo type="null"/> some text <geo type="object"> <type>Point</type> <coordinates type="array"> <value type="number">41.00502344</value> <value type="number">29.05639393</value> </coordinates></geo> ...
```

Is there any xquery function which keeps the tags and information of the elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the concat function call by returning a sequence that contains some text and the geo element, i.e.

```
for $i in db:open('foo')/bar
return ("some text ", $i/geo)
```